# Chromecast taking longer time to cast a mp4 from my host service

Tags: chromecast

I'm using iOS Chromecast app, from iPhone simulator, when I try to cast video (say, Big Buck Bunny), sample video starts almost instantly. However when I host (using godaddy.com ost service) the same video/mp4 (Bigbuckbunny.mp4) using same JSON file (videos-enhanced-b.json) from source http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/  its takes about 2 minutes to render? Any explanations are greatly appreciated.  Thanks

My media.h as below:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define MEDIA_URL_BASE @"http://www.myhosturl.com/subdirectory/"
#define MEDIA_URL_FILE @"videos-enhanced-b.json"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you open a browser and point to port 9222 on your receiver and watch as the messages come in to see what is causing the delay. The sender app sends the load message directly to your receiver, so that is obviously very fast (and that wouldn't care if your media is here or there) but after that, the receiver has to go fetch the movie from your site and render that. Watch the log to see if you notice anything unusual there. Also, from your wifi network and on your laptop, try to do download the movie (point your browser to it, for example) and see how that performs.

Comment: How to get IP/hostname of the Chromecast device, without it, I don't know how to "point to port 9222 on your receiver"/

Comment: Also I when open the mp4 file (about 150MB - Bunny) using the chrome browser, no latency observed.

Comment: Grab and android phone and install the chromecast setup application there; there you can get into the settings of each device and see their ip address

Answer (score 0):

Based on the log I got from the X-Code its takes about 3 minutes after "Media control channel metadata changed" as highlighted below.

```
2014-02-17 00:08:45.337 YouCast[1510:a0b] -[GCKMediaControlChannel didReceiveTextMessage:]  message received: {"type":"MEDIA_STATUS","status":[{"mediaSessionId":1,"playbackRate":1,"playerState":"PAUSED","currentTime":0,"supportedMediaCommands":15,"volume":{"level":1,"muted":false},"media":{"contentId":"http://myurl.com/dd1.mp4","streamType":"NONE","duration":40.77424,"contentType":"video/mp4","metadata":{"title":"Elephant Dream","images":[{"url":"http://myurl.com/images_480x270/ElephantsDream.jpg","width":200,"height":100}],"metadataType":0,"subtitle":"Blender Foundation"}}}],"requestId":3}
2014-02-17 00**:08:45.338** YouCast[1510:a0b] Media control channel status changed
**2014-02-17 0**0:08:45.34**0 YouCast[1510:a0b] Media control channel metadata changed
2014-02-17 00:08:48.617 YouCast[1510:a0b] -[GCKCastSocket socket:didReadData:withTag:]  prefix read, expected message length=248**
2014-02-17 00:08:48.618 YouCast[1510:a0b] -[GCKMediaControlChannel didReceiveTextMessage:]  message received: {"type":"MEDIA_STATUS","status":[{"mediaSessionId":1,"playbackRate":1,"playerState":"PLAYING","currentTime":1.291666,"supportedMediaCommands":15,"volume":{"level":1,"muted":false}}],"requestId":0}

Note:not able to point chrome browser  to 9222
```

Comment: It is really the receiver log that could be helpful if there is an issue. What happens if you try to cast a very short file, or a different long file? What if you serve the file locally and not through GoDaddy?

Comment: I have experimented with very short and variety of different MP4 files. BTW, its happening to the PNG and JPG files too. Anyway I try to run locally and update you.

Comment: I tried playing the file locally, it plays in the app (iOS), when I cast its fails. 2014-02-17 07:55:18.490 YouCast[3316:a0b] Casting movie file:///Users/mosesrajan/files/dd1.mp4 at starting time 0.000000     2014-02-17 07:55:20.389 YouCast[3316:a0b] -[GCKCastSocket socket:didReadData:withTag:]  prefix read, expected message length=121
2014-02-17 07:55:20.389 YouCast[3316:a0b] -[GCKMediaControlChannel didReceiveTextMessage:]  message received: {"requestId":3,"type":"LOAD_FAILED"}

Comment: I fixed this error. Local file(mp4) was start and rendered as fast as Sample Bunny video (google sample iOS). So may be Godaddy rendering is the issue.

Comment: Moving to AWS resolved the latency issue. Apparently godaddy is not a good cloud solutions for Chromecast content hosting. As Always thanks for the help Ali Naddaf.